# Call to undefined function printer_open() in Xampp 5.5.34

Tags: php, printing

I am having problem using printer_open function in xampp 5.5.34 in windows 10. I have put php_printer.dll file in php/ext folder and wrote

printer.default_printer=PHP_INI_ALL

extension=php_printer.dll

in php.ini

but still it says undefined function.

Comment: Did you figure out what was the issue? or is it still a question without an answer yet?

Comment: @Ahmad Still seems to be an issue - even with XAMPP Version 7.3.2. What is your PHP code that triggers error please?